# Try to mock pure virtual class

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

i' trying to mock a function in a pure virtual class with google mock. Here is my code:

```
class I_Circle

{

private :

public: 

    virtual ~I_Circle() {}

    virtual void GetClone(I_Circle * k) = 0;
};


class Mock_I_Circle : public I_Circle
{
public:
    Mock_I_Circle() {}
    virtual ~Mock_I_Circle() {};

    MOCK_METHOD1(GetClone, void(I_Circle* k));

};

TEST(CircleTest, secondTest) {
    NiceMock<Mock_I_Circle> iCircle;
    Mock_I_Circle* pICircle = &iCircle;

    EXPECT_CALL(iCircle, GetClone(_))
        .WillOnce(
            SetArgPointee<0>(*pICircle)
        );

    iCircle.GetClone(pICircle);

    Mock::VerifyAndClear(&iCircle);
}
```

With this implementation i'm getting the following error:

```
Error   C2280   'testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::SetArgumentPointeeAction<0,Mock_I_Circle,false>>::PolymorphicAction(const testing::PolymorphicAction<testing::internal::SetArgumentPointeeAction<0,Mock_I_Circle,false>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function MockInterface   c:\source\googletest\googlemock\include\gmock\gmock-actions.h   1110
```

What function here is meant to be deletetd? The problem seems to be result from the EXPECT_CALL with SetArgPointee, but i don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: This test is pointless, since you are trying to test your mock class, not real implementation. Please read about testing and mocking classes in general.

Comment: This is obviously correct, but I tried to keep the example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Google Mock Cookbook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md):

> SetArgPointee() conveniently makes an internal copy of the value you
>   pass to it, removing the need to keep the value in scope and alive.
>   The implication however is that the value must have a copy constructor
>   and assignment operator.

In your case, the `Mock_I_Circle` class lacks a copy constructor and assignment operator.  Adding these would fix the compilation error.  That being said, I'm not clear as to the purpose of the test you've written.

Comment: Your hints just fix this error. But our code still does not what we expect. But with the example code above, it doesn't make sense to step further but thanks for your help.

Comment: What we now experience is, that standard constructor is called once and the copy constructor is called 3 times. That seems to be very odd to me.